# Is there fat that won't be reduced?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat

I am slowly getting thinner (or less fat), but I have the impression that my double chin is not getting smaller. I know that spot reduction is largely a myth, and when exercising, my body will choose where to take fat from.

I wonder whether my body could totally ignore my double chin fat, no matter how thin I get. Is there fat that's forever there?

Comment: Kate has a great point regarding body fat percentage.  Do you happen to know your percentage body fat?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, it sounds like it will be the last to go, but it will definitely go away, this totally depends on your genetics, for me my face/arms are the first to get thinner, then my legs and back and finally the abs, also if you look at any transformation (before/after) pictures you'll see that the face does lose lots of fat. like this one http://i.imgur.com/YW6eK.jpg

Answer (score 2):

That fat will disappear if your bodyfat percentage gets low enough. There is no man with 8% bodyfat (or woman with 15% bodyfat) that has a double chin.

You probably don't need to get as low as those numbers to get rid of your double chin, but just keep working towards it. It's slow progress... you may not even notice the difference unless you're taking progress pictures.